# need to apply function to column based on values in other column python

Tags: python, lambda, apply

I have a dataframe

| ID | Job |
| --- | --- |
| 1xyz | 1 |
| 2xyz | 1 |
| 3xyz | 0 |

I want to write a function so that I split some IDs into 1_xyx and 2_xyz, but i only want to apply it to values in the ID column where job = 1.

Heres my function:

```
def add_string(string, add_str):
    return string[0] + add_string + string[1:]

df['ID'] = df.apply(lambda x:  add_string(string, '_') if df['Job'] == 1 else df['SubjID'], axis = 1)
```

I am confused

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution, use `np.where`:

```py
df["ID"] = np.where(df["Job"], df["ID"].str[0] + "_" + df["ID"].str[1:], df["ID"])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
      ID  Job
0  1_xyz    1
1  2_xyz    1
2   3xyz    0
```

---

Or:

```py
j = df.loc[df["Job"], "ID"]
df.loc[df["Job"], "ID"] = j.str[0] + "_" + j.str[1:]

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

use numpy can solve this problem

```
import pandas as pd

dit = {"ID":['1xyz', '2xyz', '3xyz'], "Job":[1, 1, 0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dit)
dfn = df.to_numpy()
mask = dfn[:, 1]==1
kk = dfn[mask, 0]
kk = map(lambda k : k[0] + "_" + k[1:], kk)
dfn[mask, 0] = list(kk)
dfn
```